# php - get data (amount) from the last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called "transactions", and in there I input the users ID, purchase type and amount everytime someone makes a purchase on my website.

I want to show these stats to each user, for the past 7 days.

Currently, I have this:

```
$data = array();
for($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++){ 
$time = time()-($x*86400);
$date = date("Y/m/d", time()-($x*86400));
$queryE = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user=:username AND time=:time AND(type='upgrade' OR type='addrbl' OR type='clicks' OR type='banner') ");
$queryE->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
$queryE->bindParam(":time",$time);
$queryE->execute();

$row=$queryE->fetch();
$data[] = ($row['amount'] > 0 ? $row['amount'] : 0);
$dates[] = date("Y/m/d", time()-($x*86400));   


}
$days = array('Today');
for ($i=0; $i<7;$i++)
{
  $days[$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-'.($i+0).' day'));
}
```

And then to print it, I have this:

```
echo implode(',', $data);
```

Although above code simply prints out 0,0,0,0,0,0,0

If I remove the `$time` from the query, then it only select the first row and print out that for each day.

Example: If someone purchased 3 things, but the first thing costed $60, then it will print out `60,60,60,60,60,60,60`

Can someone please help me how to select the sum of the amount, from each day and print it out?

Comment: post some sample data and table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited after learning `time` is a unix timestamp in db**

Currently you are trying to fetch records for a given time (not date). Since you have a unix timestamp field `time` on db, you need to give an interval. Also, as there might be multiple purchases on a day, you need to `SUM` all `amounts` for a given date.

```
...
$begin = strtotime('today midnight');
for($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++) {
  $end = $begin + 86400;
  $queryE = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM transactions WHERE user=:username AND time > :begin AND time <= :end AND(type='upgrade' OR type='addrbl' OR type='clicks' OR type='banner') ");
  $queryE->bindParam(":username",$userdata['id']);
  $queryE->bindParam(":begin", $begin);
  $queryE->bindParam(":end", $end);
  $queryE->execute();

  $row=$queryE->fetch();
  $data[] = $row['total'];
  $dates[] = date("Y/m/d", $begin);
  $begin -= 86400;
}
...
```

Comment: the "time" field in the database is a unix timestamp.

Comment: Then you cannot fetch records as time=:time, you need to specify an interval. Let me update my answer.